# XAMPP - my ip directs to router setup config instead of home server

Tags: apache, ip, xampp, portforwarding

I want to access my home server from the internet. I configured my router to forward 192.168.8.3 my IPv4 address port 80 to 80. But when I attempt to go to my IP address 43.xx.xxx.xx it redirect me to the router's setup page, but when I type 192.168.8.3, it directs me right to my html.

The Apache config is allowing all.

Please comment me, so I can provide useful information.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to restart Apache service when I done correcting the Apache config, it didn't work. It requires a restart of computer to activate the correction... I am so unintelligent.